# Spring boot saving separate entities in same method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have an method that operates on two separate entities that are not directly related, they are both related in @ManyToOne relation to same third entity.

I save them both in same method, but only the second save is persisted to database. I found information that save() method usually is flushed to database at the exit of method which might be the issue, and using JPA saveAndFlush should fix it, but the result is same. The first save is ignored.

```
firstEntity.setSomething("10");
firstEntity = firstEntityManager.save(firstEntity);
//It's fine here, it prints 10
System.out.println(firstEntity.getSomething());
secondEntity.setFlag(true);
secondEntity = secondEntityManager.save(secondEntity);
//method end, first entity is not being updated in database
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: where do the entities come from? Are they already managed by the EntityManager? And (why) do you use two separate entity managers?

Comment: @cyberbrain They come from two findBy methods, entity manager in that case is just a service that redirect called method to repository

Comment: Please post some actual code instead of psuedo code. Make sure that this code is in a single method that is annotated with `@Transactional`.